# Azure Mobile App Server doesn't return DBGeography on GET

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

My instance of Microsoft Azure Mobile App Server will happily store a DBGeography POINT() as a table column, which is contained in the JSON data confirming that a POST has been made.

**My 'Location' data object:**

```
public DbGeography Location { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
```

**My controller:**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostI4Item([FromBody] IslandFourEntity item)
    {
        var coordinates = DbGeography.FromText($"POINT({item.Longitude} {item.Latitude})");
        item.Location = coordinates;
        
        IslandFourEntity current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
```

**Postman response after 'POST' request:**

```
{
"body": "Test body value",
"subject": "Test subject value",
"type": "type",
"location": {
    "geography": {
        "coordinateSystemId": 4326,
        "wellKnownText": "POINT (172.590401 -43.539994)"
    }
},
"longitude": 172.590401,
"latitude": -43.539994,
"id": "58542f5ee84d4867ae1f3d2c3b098b1b",
"version": "AAAAAAAAD6I=",
"createdAt": "2021-03-05T00:16:12.292Z",
"updatedAt": "2021-03-05T00:16:12.731Z",
"deleted": false
```

}

However if you GET all table values, or just one individual item, the column containing the DBGeography item isn't contained within (despite definitely being saved in the database.)

Default GET response for that record:

```
{
"deleted": false,
"updatedAt": "2021-03-05T00:16:12.731Z",
"createdAt": "2021-03-05T00:16:12.292Z",
"version": "AAAAAAAAD6I=",
"id": "58542f5ee84d4867ae1f3d2c3b098b1b",
"type": "type",
"subject": "Test subject value",
"body": "Test body value"
```

}

As you can see, every other column was returned except for 'Location'.

So this question is probably more for anyone who has had experience with Microsoft Azure Mobile App Services, but how can you modify the default Query() method to serialise DBGeography into a string?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you get an `IQueryable<T>` back and then it is serialized by the ASP.NET OData (v3) system or the Node.js system (you don't say which you are using).  There are two issues here - what the IQueryable is returning, and what oData does with it.

Since it is an OData v3 endpoint, try adding `?$expand=location` to see if that will expand the output.  Read up on the $expand option in [the docs](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/) - section 5.1.3 covers $expand.

Comment: I was really excited to try your suggestion, but when I added $expand=location it only returned '"location": {}' which I guess is showing that a set of data is there, but what it is returning is empty.  Still looking for a fix.

Comment: You will likely need to use a custom Newtonsoft.JSON converter to ensure that the Location is not nested two levels deep.  i.e. `"location": "POINT(x,y)"` instead of what you are doing.  That way you don't need to do a $expand either.